# JSONObject has value but returns null value

Tags: java, android, json, api

```
[
{
    "valve": "4679",
    "selling": "5516",
    "bal": "9075.4",
    "o id": "37",
    "invested": "11122",      //<<<<<<<- this value returns null
    "aProfit": "1012",      //<<<<<<<- this value returns null
    "count": "182",      //<<<<<<<- this value returns null
    "cost": "5051"      //<<<<<<<- this value returns null
}
]
```

.- The JSONObject above requested from onPostExecute

```
    @Override
protected void onPostExecute (String ANSWER)
{   String u_id;

    try{
        JSONArray jsonArray = null;
        jsonArray = new JSONArray(ANSWER);
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); )
        {
            JSONObject JO = (JSONObject) jsonArray.get(i);
            jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

            CASH = (String) jsonObject.getString("bal");
            USER_VALUE = (String) jsonObject.getString("valve");
            INVEST = (String) jsonObject.getString("invested");
            PROFIT = (String) jsonObject.getString("aProfit");
            COST_P = (String) jsonObject.getString("cost");
            COUNT = (String) jsonObject.getString("count");

    DashBoard.mprofit.setText(PROFIT);
    DashBoard.minvest.setText(INVEST);
    DashBoard.massets.setText(COST_P);
    DashBoard.mvalue.setText(USER_VALUE);  //<<<<<<<- this value returns the value.
```

Many others do, but some just refused to return and when I cross-check with postman, they all return.
so am now confused because if I swap the places of the `valve` and the `count` in the webservices code, it is no more null and vice versa.

Short question: can someone please explain why some values return null in the java coding.

Comment: Why is your loop missing `i++`?

Comment: Please debug the code and check whether you are getting value in `ANSWER`? also please provide more code from where you are calling `onPostExecute`

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please post your code calling API methods

Comment: why you taking two object i.e `JO` and `jsonObject ` ?

Comment: @Gendarme - where is the `i++` to be

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try {

```
        JSONArray jsonArray = null;
        jsonArray = new JSONArray(ANSWER);
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); ) {
            JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) jsonArray.get(i);
            //jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i); **remove this line thne check remove this line thne check**

            String CASH = (String) jsonObject.getString("bal");
            String USER_VALUE = (String) jsonObject.getString("valve");
            String INVEST = (String) jsonObject.getString("invested");
            String PROFIT = (String) jsonObject.getString("aProfit");
            String COST_P = (String) jsonObject.getString("cost");
            String COUNT = (String) jsonObject.getString("count");


        }
    }catch (Exception e){
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 try {

            JSONArray jsonArray = null;
            jsonArray = new JSONArray(ANSWER);
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); ) {
                JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) jsonArray.get(i);
                jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                String CASH = (String) jsonObject.getString("bal");
                String USER_VALUE = (String) jsonObject.getString("valve");
                String INVEST = (String) jsonObject.getString("invested");
                String PROFIT = (String) jsonObject.getString("aProfit");
                String COST_P = (String) jsonObject.getString("cost");
                String COUNT = (String) jsonObject.getString("count");


            }
        }catch (Exception e){
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this code:

```
try {

        JSONArray jsonArray = null;
        jsonArray = new JSONArray(ANSWER);
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); ) {
            JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) jsonArray.get(i);
            jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

            String valve = (String) jsonObject.getString("valve");
            String selling = (String) jsonObject.getString("selling");
            String bal = (String) jsonObject.getString("bal");
            String o_id = (String) jsonObject.getString("o_id");
            String invested = (String) jsonObject.getString("invested");
            String aProfit = (String) jsonObject.getString("aProfit");
            String count = (String) jsonObject.getString("count");
            String cost = (String) jsonObject.getString("cost");
        }
    }catch (Exception e){
    }
```

Hope this helps...
Happy Coding :)